# Magento 2.4.6 admin category URL redirect admin dashboard

Tags: admin, category, url, magento2.4.2

Admin category URL link redirects to admin dashboard issue how to fix this issue

Current URL: Category

https://test.cm/mv2/admin/catalog/category/edit/id/12/key/a7294ff98a7d8ff0eb16dbf92bd5ffae4da9620da389376dff80aa82e4d42b60/

Real category URL

https://test.com/mv2/admin/catalog/category/edit/key/30dcd45cded283314a2410b81138a716658363d538381032f0bb16e3f66d14d0/id/12/

```
 public function getCategoryEditUrl()
{ 
    $category=$this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    return $this->backendUrl->getUrl('catalog/category/edit', ['id' => $category->getId()]);
}
```

above code get

> https://test.cm/mv2/admin/catalog/category/edit/id/12/key/a7294ff98a7d8ff0eb16dbf92bd5ffae4da9620da389376dff80aa82e4d42b60/

this URL but the real URL this

> https://test.com/mv2/admin/catalog/category/edit/key/30dcd45cded283314a2410b81138a716658363d538381032f0bb16e3f66d14d0/id/12/

advance thanks thanks for the help.

Comment: Where did you generate the URL? On the frontend? In an email?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this code.

```
public function getCategoryEditUrl()
{
    
    $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    
    return $this->backendUrl->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog/category/edit', ['id' => $category->getId()]);
}
```

Comment: use this code @dhiren vasoya
public function getCategoryEditUrl()
 {
  $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
  
  $categoryId = $category->getId();
  
  $url = $this->helperBackend->getUrl(
        'catalog/category/edit',
        ['_query' => ['key' => $this->session->getSecurity()->getFormKey()], 'id' => $categoryId]);
  
  return $url;
 }

but not working

Comment: I update answer, kindly check those.

Comment: already tired this but not working
@Dhiren Vasoya

Answer (score 0):

> **Please use the code below to get the admin URL.**

```
protected $backendUrl;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
) {
    $this->backendUrl = $backendUrl;
}

public function getCategoryEditUrl()
{
    return $this->backendUrl->getUrl('catalog/category/edit',['id' => '4']);
}
```

**It's redirecting to the dashboard because key validation has failed. You can disable the key from the store configuration and check it again.**
[image]

Comment: Add Secret Key to URLs set no then working but this is not the proper solution so please provide me another solution. @Msquare

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala Where did you generate the URL? On the frontend? In an email?